# Java Minecraft Error

Tags: java, minecraft

I have a little problem, but I can´t find it.

So when I try to start Minecraft it loads Forge and so on but my mod crashs since I made a really big update and now I cant even start minecraft anymore

So I went to Stack Overflow to get some hints what I did wrong
Thanks in advance.

I´m very grateful for any help!

Here is my code

```
package com.woodcore.main;

import com.woodcore.armor.*;
import com.woodcore.block.*;
import com.woodcore.item.*;

import cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod.EventHandler;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.event.FMLInitializationEvent;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.event.FMLPostInitializationEvent;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.event.FMLPreInitializationEvent;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry;
import net.minecraft.block.Block;
import net.minecraft.block.material.Material;
import net.minecraft.creativetab.CreativeTabs;
import net.minecraft.init.Items;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemArmor;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemFood;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemStack;
import net.minecraftforge.common.util.EnumHelper;

@Mod(modid = "WoodCore", name = "WoodCore", version = "1.4.2")

public class WoodCore 
{
//**Tool Material**//
public static final Item.ToolMaterial JadeToolMaterial = EnumHelper.addToolMaterial("JadeToolMaterial", 4, 1350, 9.0F, 5.0F, 30);
public static final Item.ToolMaterial PsionicToolMaterial = EnumHelper.addToolMaterial("PsionicToolMaterial", 4, 1500, 9.0F, 5.0F, 30);
public static final Item.ToolMaterial RedstoneToolMaterial = EnumHelper.addToolMaterial("RedstoneToolMaterial", 5, 1650, 10.0F, 6.0F, 30);
public static final Item.ToolMaterial JadeGoldToolMaterial = EnumHelper.addToolMaterial("JadeGoldToolMaterial", 5, 1800, 10.0F, 6.0F, 30);
public static final Item.ToolMaterial AquaticToolMaterial = EnumHelper.addToolMaterial("AquaticToolMaterial", 6, 1950, 11.0F, 7.0F, 30);
//**Armor Material**//
public static final ItemArmor.ArmorMaterial JadeArmorMaterial = EnumHelper.addArmorMaterial("JadeArmorMaterial", 1350, new int[]{4,8,6,3}, 30);
public static final ItemArmor.ArmorMaterial PsionicArmorMaterial = EnumHelper.addArmorMaterial("PsionicArmorMaterial", 1500, new int[]{5,9,7,5}, 30);
//Blocks
public static Block blockJade;
public static Block blockPsionic;
public static Block blockRedstoneModded;
public static Block blockAquatic;
public static Block blockAquaticRedstone;
public static Block blockJadeGold;
//**Ingots**//
public static Item ingotJade;
public static Item ingotPsionicBase;
public static Item ingotPsionic;
public static Item ingotJadeGold;
public static Item ingotRedstone;
public static Item ingotAquatic;
public static Item ingotAquaticRedstone;
//**Nuggets**//
//**Armor Items!**//
public static Item jadeHelm;
public static Item jadeChest;
public static Item jadeLeggins;
public static Item jadeBoots;
//Swords
public static Item JadeSword;
public static Item PsionicSword;
public static Item RedstoneSword;
public static Item JadeGoldSword;
//Pickaxes
public static Item JadePickaxe;
public static Item PsionicPickaxe;
public static Item RedstonePickaxe;
public static Item AquaticPickaxe;
public static Item AquaticRedstonePickaxe;
public static Item JadeGoldPickaxe;
//Axes
public static Item JadeAxe;
public static Item PsionicAxe;
public static Item RedstoneAxe;
public static Item JadeGoldAxe;
//Shovels
public static Item JadeShovel;
public static Item PsionicShovel;
public static Item RedstoneShovel;
public static Item JadeGoldShovel;
//Food
public static Item foodJadeApple;
public static Item foodPsionicApple;
public static Item foodRedstoneApple;
public static Item foodAquaticApple;
public static Item foodAquaticRedApple;

@EventHandler
public void preInit(FMLPreInitializationEvent event)
{
    System.out.print("Loading Wood Core Mod!");
    //ItemInit
    ingotJade = new IngotJade().setUnlocalizedName("IngotJade").setTextureName("WoodCore:ingotJade").setCreativeTab(tabWoodCore);
    ingotPsionic = new IngotPsionic().setUnlocalizedName("IngotPsionic").setTextureName("WoodCore:ingotPsionic").setCreativeTab(tabWoodCore);
    ingotPsionicBase = new IngotPsionicBase().setUnlocalizedName("IngotPsionicBase").setTextureName("WoodCore:ingotPsionicBase").setCreativeTab(tabWoodCore);
    ingotRedstone = new IngotRedstone().setUnlocalizedName("IngotRedstone").setTextureName("WoodCore:ingotRedstone").setCreativeTab(tabWoodCore);
    ingotJadeGold = new IngotJadeGold().setUnlocalizedName("IngotJadeGold").setTextureName("WoodCore:ingotJadeGold").setCreativeTab(tabWoodCore);
    ingotAquatic = new IngotAquatic().setUnlocalizedName("IngotAquatic").setTextureName("WoodCore:ingotAquatic").setCreativeTab(tabWoodCore);
    ingotAquaticRedstone = new IngotAquaticRedstone().setUnlocalizedName("IngotAquaticRedstone").setTextureName("WoodCore:ingotAquaticRedstone");
    //BlockInit
    blockJade = new BlockJade(Material.iron).setBlockName("BlockJade").setBlockTextureName("WoodCore:blockJade").setCreativeTab(tabWoodCore);
    blockPsionic = new BlockPsionic(Material.iron).setBlockName("BlockPsionic").setBlockTextureName("WoodCore:blockPsionic").setCreativeTab(tabWoodCore);
    blockRedstoneModded = new BlockRedstoneModded(Material.iron).setBlockName("BlockRedstoneModded").setBlockTextureName("WoodCore:blockRedstone").setCreativeTab(tabWoodCore);
    blockAquatic = new BlockAquatic(Material.iron).setBlockName("BlockAquatic").setBlockTextureName("WoodCore:blockAquatic").setCreativeTab(tabWoodCore);
    blockAquaticRedstone = new BlockAquaticRedstone(Material.iron).setBlockName("BlockAquaticRedstone").setBlockTextureName("WoodCore:blockAquaticRedstone").setCreativeTab(tabWoodCore);
    blockJadeGold = new BlockJadeGold(Material.iron).setBlockName("BlockJadeGold").setBlockTextureName("WoodCore:blockJadeGold").setCreativeTab(tabWoodCore);
    //**FoodInit (X * 0.5 = Y Hunger)**//
    foodPsionicApple = new ItemFood(6, 0.8F, false).setUnlocalizedName("PsionicApple").setTextureName("WoodCore:psionicApple").setCreativeTab(tabWoodCore);
    //ToolInit
    JadePickaxe = new JadePickaxe(JadeToolMaterial).setUnlocalizedName("JadePickaxe").setTextureName("WoodCore:JjdePickaxe").setCreativeTab(tabWoodCore);
    PsionicPickaxe = new PsionicPickaxe(PsionicToolMaterial).setUnlocalizedName("PsionicPickaxe").setTextureName("WoodCore:psionicPickaxe").setCreativeTab(tabWoodCore);
    RedstonePickaxe = new RedstonePickaxe(RedstoneToolMaterial).setUnlocalizedName("RedstonePickaxe").setTextureName("WoodCore:redstonePickaxe").setCreativeTab(tabWoodCore);
    AquaticPickaxe = new AquaticPickaxe(AquaticToolMaterial).setUnlocalizedName("AquaticPickaxe").setTextureName("WoodCore:aquaticPickaxe").setCreativeTab(tabWoodCore);
    JadeGoldPickaxe = new JadeGoldPickaxe(JadeGoldToolMaterial).setUnlocalizedName("JadeGoldPickaxe").setTextureName("WoodCore:jadeGoldPickaxe").setCreativeTab(tabWoodCore);

    JadeAxe = new JadeAxe(JadeToolMaterial).setUnlocalizedName("JadeAxe").setTextureName("WoodCore:jadeAxe").setCreativeTab(tabWoodCore);
    PsionicAxe = new PsionicAxe(PsionicToolMaterial).setUnlocalizedName("PsionicAxe").setTextureName("WoodCore:psionicAxe").setCreativeTab(tabWoodCore);
    JadeGoldAxe = new JadeGoldAxe(JadeGoldToolMaterial).setUnlocalizedName("JadeGoldAxe").setTextureName("WoodCore:jadeGoldAxe").setCreativeTab(tabWoodCore);

    JadeShovel = new JadeShovel(JadeToolMaterial).setUnlocalizedName("JadeShovel").setTextureName("WoodCore:jadeShovel").setCreativeTab(tabWoodCore);
    PsionicShovel = new PsionicShovel(PsionicToolMaterial).setUnlocalizedName("PsionicShovel").setTextureName("WoodCore:psionicShovel").setCreativeTab(tabWoodCore);
    JadeGoldShovel = new JadeGoldShovel(JadeGoldToolMaterial).setUnlocalizedName("JadeGoldShovel").setTextureName("WoodCore:jadeGoldShovel").setCreativeTab(tabWoodCore);

    JadeSword = new JadeSword(JadeToolMaterial).setUnlocalizedName("JadeSword").setTextureName("WoodCore:jadeSword").setCreativeTab(tabWoodCore);
    PsionicSword = new PsionicSword(PsionicToolMaterial).setUnlocalizedName("PsionicSword").setTextureName("WoodCore:psionicSword").setCreativeTab(tabWoodCore);
    JadeGoldSword = new JadeGoldSword(JadeGoldToolMaterial).setUnlocalizedName("JadeGoldSword").setTextureName("WoodCore:jadeGoldSword").setCreativeTab(tabWoodCore);
    //**Armor Init**//
    jadeHelm = new JadeArmor(JadeArmorMaterial, 0, 0);
    jadeHelm = new JadeArmor(JadeArmorMaterial, 0, 1);
    jadeHelm = new JadeArmor(JadeArmorMaterial, 0, 2);
    jadeHelm = new JadeArmor(JadeArmorMaterial, 0, 3);
    //**Item Registry**//
    GameRegistry.registerItem(ingotJade, ingotJade.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));
    GameRegistry.registerItem(ingotPsionic, ingotPsionic.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));
    GameRegistry.registerItem(ingotPsionicBase, ingotPsionicBase.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));
    GameRegistry.registerItem(ingotRedstone, ingotRedstone.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));
    GameRegistry.registerItem(ingotJadeGold, ingotJadeGold.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));
    GameRegistry.registerItem(ingotAquatic, ingotAquatic.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));
    GameRegistry.registerItem(ingotAquaticRedstone, ingotAquaticRedstone.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));
    //Block Registry
    GameRegistry.registerBlock(blockJade, blockJade.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));
    System.out.println(blockJade.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));
    GameRegistry.registerBlock(blockPsionic, blockPsionic.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));
    System.out.println(blockPsionic.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));
    GameRegistry.registerBlock(blockRedstoneModded, blockRedstoneModded.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));
    System.out.println(blockRedstoneModded.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));
    GameRegistry.registerBlock(blockAquatic, blockAquatic.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));
    System.out.println(blockAquatic.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));
    GameRegistry.registerBlock(blockJadeGold, blockJadeGold.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));
    System.out.println(blockJadeGold.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));
    GameRegistry.registerBlock(blockAquaticRedstone, blockAquaticRedstone.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));
    System.out.println(blockAquaticRedstone.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));
    //Food Registry
    GameRegistry.registerItem(foodPsionicApple, foodPsionicApple.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));
    //Tool Registry
    GameRegistry.registerItem(JadePickaxe, JadePickaxe.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));
    GameRegistry.registerItem(PsionicPickaxe, PsionicPickaxe.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));
    GameRegistry.registerItem(RedstonePickaxe, RedstonePickaxe.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));
    GameRegistry.registerItem(JadeGoldPickaxe, JadeGoldPickaxe.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));
    GameRegistry.registerItem(AquaticPickaxe, AquaticPickaxe.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));

    //**Armor Registry**//
    GameRegistry.registerItem(jadeHelm, jadeHelm.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));
    GameRegistry.registerItem(jadeChest, jadeChest.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));
    GameRegistry.registerItem(jadeLeggins, jadeLeggins.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));
    GameRegistry.registerItem(jadeBoots, jadeBoots.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));

}
@EventHandler
public void Init(FMLInitializationEvent event)
{
    //**Blocks > Ingots**//
    GameRegistry.addRecipe(new ItemStack(ingotJade, 9), new Object[]{"   ", " j ", "   ", 'j', WoodCore.blockJade});
    GameRegistry.addRecipe(new ItemStack(ingotPsionic, 9), new Object[]{"   ", " p ", "   ", 'p', WoodCore.blockPsionic});
    GameRegistry.addRecipe(new ItemStack(ingotRedstone, 9), new Object[]{"   ", " r ", "   ", 'r', WoodCore.blockRedstoneModded});
    GameRegistry.addRecipe(new ItemStack(ingotAquatic, 9), new Object[]{"   ", " j ", "   ", 'j', WoodCore.blockAquatic});
    GameRegistry.addRecipe(new ItemStack(ingotJadeGold, 9), new Object[]{"   ", " j ", "   ", 'j', WoodCore.blockJadeGold});
    GameRegistry.addRecipe(new ItemStack(ingotAquaticRedstone, 9), new Object[]{"   ", " j ", "   ", 'j', WoodCore.blockAquaticRedstone});

    //**Ingots > Blocks**//
    GameRegistry.addRecipe(new ItemStack(blockJade), new Object[]{"JJJ", "JJJ", "JJJ", 'J', ingotJade});
    GameRegistry.addRecipe(new ItemStack(blockPsionic), new Object[]{"PPP", "PPP", "PPP", 'P', ingotPsionic});
    GameRegistry.addRecipe(new ItemStack(blockRedstoneModded), new Object[]{"RRR", "RRR", "RRR", 'R', ingotRedstone});

    //Pickaxes
    GameRegistry.addRecipe(new ItemStack(JadePickaxe), new Object[]{"JJJ", " s ", " s ", 'J', ingotJade, 's', Items.stick});
    GameRegistry.addRecipe(new ItemStack(PsionicPickaxe), new Object[]{"PPP", " s ", " s ", 'P', ingotPsionic, 's', Items.stick});
    GameRegistry.addRecipe(new ItemStack(RedstonePickaxe), new Object[]{"RRR", " s ", " s ", 'R', ingotRedstone, 's', Items.stick});
    GameRegistry.addRecipe(new ItemStack(JadeGoldPickaxe), new Object[]{"JJJ", " s ", " s ", 'J', ingotJadeGold, 's', Items.stick});    
}
@EventHandler
public void postInit(FMLPostInitializationEvent event)
{
    System.out.print("Loaded Wood Core Mod successfully!"+ "Have fun!");
}

public static CreativeTabs tabWoodCore = new CreativeTabs("tabWoodCore"){
    @Override
    public Item getTabIconItem()
    {
        return new ItemStack(WoodCore.ingotPsionic).getItem();
    }`
};  
}
```

Error Log

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// My bad.

Time: 22.02.17 03:29
Description: Initializing game

java.lang.NullPointerException: Initializing game
at com.woodcore.main.WoodCore.preInit(WoodCore.java:162)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at                  cpw.mods.fml.common.FMLModContainer.handleModStateEvent(FMLModContainer.java:532)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber.handleEvent(EventSubscriber.java:74)
at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventSubscriber.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventSubscriber.java:47)
at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:322)
at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:304)
at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275)
at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.sendEventToModContainer(LoadController.java:212)
at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.propogateStateMessage(LoadController.java:190)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber.handleEvent(EventSubscriber.java:74)
at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventSubscriber.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventSubscriber.java:47)
at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:322)
at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:304)
at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275)
at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.distributeStateMessage(LoadController.java:119)
at cpw.mods.fml.common.Loader.preinitializeMods(Loader.java:556)
at cpw.mods.fml.client.FMLClientHandler.beginMinecraftLoading(FMLClientHandler.java:243)
at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.startGame(Minecraft.java:522)
at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:942)
at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:164)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135)
at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
at net.minecraftforge.gradle.GradleStartCommon.launch(Unknown Source)
at GradleStart.main(Unknown Source)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Stacktrace:
at com.woodcore.main.WoodCore.preInit(WoodCore.java:162)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at     cpw.mods.fml.common.FMLModContainer.handleModStateEvent(FMLModContainer.java:532)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber.handleEvent(EventSubscriber.java:74)
at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventSubscriber.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventSubscriber.java:47)
at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:322)
at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:304)
at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275)
at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.sendEventToModContainer(LoadController.java:212)
at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.propogateStateMessage(LoadController.java:190)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber.handleEvent(EventSubscriber.java:74)
at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventSubscriber.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventSubscriber.java:47)
at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:322)
at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:304)
at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275)
at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.distributeStateMessage(LoadController.java:119)
at cpw.mods.fml.common.Loader.preinitializeMods(Loader.java:556)
at cpw.mods.fml.client.FMLClientHandler.beginMinecraftLoading(FMLClientHandler.java:243)
at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.startGame(Minecraft.java:522)

-- Initialization --
Details:
Stacktrace:
at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:942)
at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:164)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135)
at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
at net.minecraftforge.gradle.GradleStartCommon.launch(Unknown Source)
at GradleStart.main(Unknown Source)

-- System Details --
Details:
Minecraft Version: 1.7.10
Operating System: Windows 10 (amd64) version 10.0
Java Version: 1.8.0_121, Oracle Corporation
Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
Memory: 818380864 bytes (780 MB) / 1056309248 bytes (1007 MB) up to 1056309248 bytes (1007 MB)
JVM Flags: 3 total; -Xincgc -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M
AABB Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
FML: MCP v9.05 FML v7.10.99.99 Minecraft Forge 10.13.4.1558 4 mods loaded, 4 mods active
States: 'U' = Unloaded 'L' = Loaded 'C' = Constructed 'H' = Pre-initialized 'I' = Initialized 'J' = Post-initialized 'A' = Available 'D' = Disabled 'E' = Errored
UCH mcp{9.05} [Minecraft Coder Pack] (minecraft.jar) 
UCH FML{7.10.99.99} [Forge Mod Loader] (forgeSrc-1.7.10-10.13.4.1558-1.7.10.jar) 
UCH Forge{10.13.4.1558} [Minecraft Forge] (forgeSrc-1.7.10-10.13.4.1558-1.7.10.jar) 
UCE WoodCore{1.4.2} [WoodCore] (bin) 
GL info: ' Vendor: 'Intel' Version: '4.3.0 - Build 10.18.15.4256' Renderer: 'Intel(R) HD Graphics'
Launched Version: 1.7.10
LWJGL: 2.9.1
OpenGL: Intel(R) HD Graphics GL version 4.3.0 - Build 10.18.15.4256, Intel
GL Caps: Using GL 1.3 multitexturing.
Using framebuffer objects because OpenGL 3.0 is supported and separate     blending is supported.
Anisotropic filtering is supported and maximum anisotropy is 16.
Shaders are available because OpenGL 2.1 is supported.

Is Modded: Definitely; Client brand changed to 'fml,forge'
Type: Client (map_client.txt)
Resource Packs: []
Current Language: English (US)
Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
Vec3 Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
Anisotropic Filtering: Off (1)
```

Comment: Java doesn't (often) crash. Java throws exceptions which tell you what the problem is and where it occurred.

Comment: Yes I know but, I can´t find this exception, and the error log says Something in the PreInit caused an exception @John3136

Comment: Does it tell you what the exception is? (because you haven't told us).

Comment: When Minecraft crashes, a dialog box with text appears, showing the (nearly full) exception. Check your Minecraft logs again?

Comment: Wait a second please @John3136

Comment: @John3136 I added it

Comment: Sorry, this is not how StackOverflow works.  Questions of the form _"Here's a bunch of my code, please debug it for me"_ are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask] for more information.

Answer (score 3):

`jadeChest` is never initialized, therefore it is `null` so when you try to do `jadeChest.getUnlocalizedName()` you get a NPE.

Comment: Now I see the problem

Comment: Upvote and/or accept the answer if it helped is the way things work here.

Answer (score 0):

`jadeChest`
is not initialized and it is defaultly set to null, and there you have a `java.lang.NullPointerException`. It happens when an object reference has a value of null, it gives that error. Can I ask is this a Mod you developed or found? I am guessing you are trying to use the Jade mod.